# How do I fix SIPEPS reference missing from UCMA InstantMessagingCall quick start sample

Tags: c#, .net, ucma

I’m attempting to work with UCMA sample and came across https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454827(v=office.16).aspx 
I installed the SDK from https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn465959(v=office.16).aspx and have the pre-requisites, but for some reason when I run the sample I’m facing an error like:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'SIPEPS, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"SIPEPS, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"}
```

Is anyone aware why I might be receiving this error from the out-of-the-box sample? Know how to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648356/error-sipeps-version-5-0-0-0-ucma-4-0-vs2010-vs2013/35412358#35412358

Answer (score 15):

I was able to solve this by setting the project architecture to x64. This seems to have corrected the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I, also, was able to solve the problem by setting the project architecture to x64. The UCMA code seems to demand that we stay in a 64-Bit environment.
To the new programmers, the specific steps I took:

- When in a Visual Studio text editor you typically see the "Standard Toolbar". By default the 1st window on the toolbar reads "Debug" and the 2nd window reads "Any CPU". To the right of "Any CPU" click the small black triangle to bring up a combo-box style list of items. Select "Configuration Manager..."
- Within the Configuration Manager dialog that comes up, under the "Platform" column, change "Any CPU" to "x64".
- Click the "Close" button in the lower right of the dialog.
- Upon running the app with either  or "Debug Menu, "Start Debugging" the problem disappears.