# UCMA 6.0 App built for X64 works on 1st laptop, fails on 2nd laptop with: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: . . . 'SIPEPS, Version=7.0.0.0

Tags: skype-for-business, ucma

Built a UMCA 6.0 APP on Laptop 1 with platform target set to x64 and framework target set to .Net Framework 4.8.  Laptop 1 is X64 based CPU running Windows 10 Enterprise.  Application runs as designed.

Copied the executable and DLLs to Laptop 2, where UCMA runtime and .NetFramework 4.8 were installed.  The process also required installing Visual C++ 2015-2019 redistribution.  Got the infamous SIPEPS error message.

Copied the project directory (source code, project file, etc.) to Laptop 2 and rebuilt the app after doing a clean.  Confirmed project properties included X64 and .Net Framework 4.8.  Build was successful 1st time. Ran the app and still getting the SIPEPS error message.

Both laptops are Dells with i7 cores.  Using VS 2017 for build.  Need to have a backup machine for this app. If the primary fails - we are dead in the water.

Comment: At a guess I'd say replication hasn't been set up correctly on the 2nd laptop.  This post covers a number of causes for SIPEPS errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648356/error-sipeps-version-5-0-0-0-ucma-4-0-vs2010-vs2013/31672880#31672880

Comment: @Hodgson What switch(es) are needed?  I tried the -CentralManagmentStoreStatus switch but got an SQL error message - Login failed. This is an end user app ran on a corporate laptop. The only server I am aware of is the one used when establishing an endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You must uninstall all Visual C++ releases greater than 2013 before UCMA 6.0 will properly install.  I also did a repair of .Net Framework 4.8.  Installed UCMA 6.0 before anything else and that seems to have addressed this particular issue.

Now its on to a new issue: "Recorder cannot start due to I/O Error."